# How to read Hibernate L2 cache and Spring cache region contents

Tags: hibernate, caching, ehcache, second-level-cache, spring-cache

We use Hibernate L2 cache and also Spring cache in our project an we need to be able to read the cache contents on server for troubleshooting. Both caches are backed by EhCache in our case.

We need a way to read the cache content and display it in an UI directly in our application (we cannot install third-party applications on the customers server, like for instance EhCache-monitor). As I see it, there are 2 ways of approaching this:

1. Read the contents of L2 cache through Hibernate, and Spring cache through Spring, regardless of the backing cache implementation (this would be the preferred way).
2. Read the contents of all cache regions in EhCache, regardless of whether they belong to Spring or Hibernate.

I tried some googling but oddly enough, I didn't find a satisfying answer yet. I mean, we cannot be the first ones to need such a feature.

Do you have any suggestions? Any point to the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: I fail to see how inspecting the content of the cache would be any helpful. If your application behaves differently when caching is on, something wrong is going on elsewhere. That being said, ehcache has JMX endpoints for the caches so you could use that. Spring's abstraction has nothing of the kind (basically for the reason I mentioned above).